# Bundle getExtras() works only once then errors

Tags: java, android

I store the text of a button pushed using the getExtras. The text is a file name. I'm using this method because I'm passing it to another activity. I can retrieve it once, then I get a file not found error. Here's my code.

This is for the main.java file which gets the text of the button and stores it. This works.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button button = (Button)v;
    String btnText = button.getText().toString();
    // Used for debug
    System.out.println("In Main (btnText) --  " + btnText);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("btnNameStored", btnText);

    Intent showPart = new Intent(this, PartActivity.class);
    showPart.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(showPart);
```

Then I get it in my other activity.

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String btnPushed = bundle.getString("btnNameStored");
    String btnName = btnPushed + ".txt";
    // Used for debug
    System.out.println("Part Java (btnName)  --  " +btnName);

    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open(btnName);
```

This is the line it fails on.
InputStream is = getAssets().open(btnName);

This is the part that only works once. Both files are in assets folder. 
The buttons are lined up in a grid, two cols and x rows. If you push the button in row 1 col 2, it fails. Only if you push the button in row 1 col 1 does it work. Not sure why only the first button pushed works.

Thanks in advance,

Here's the exception - W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: round.txt

[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKBYq.jpg)

Comment: Can you add the exception from the logcat to your question?

Comment: Are you sure both files exist ? Can you put the entire code for both the activities ?

Comment: Here you go. I just added it also. W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: round.txt

Comment: please. stop in line `InputStream is = getAssets().open(btnName);` with debugger and show us your btnName. And pass your file name :)

Comment: Yes both file exist. If I hard code the file name it works for both. Only when I try to get it dynamically does it only work for the first time.

Comment: Here's the first time it works. 01-25 10:46:24.050 27722-27722/com.example.neil.hvacbuilder I/System.out: In Main (btnText) --  square
01-25 10:46:24.060 27722-27722/com.example.neil.hvacbuilder I/System.out: Part Java (btnName)  --  square.txt

Comment: Here's the time it fails.  01-25 10:46:34.680 27722-27722/com.example.neil.hvacbuilder I/System.out: In Main (btnText) --  round
01-25 10:46:34.700 27722-27722/com.example.neil.hvacbuilder I/System.out: Part Java (btnName)  --  round.txt
01-25 10:46:34.700 27722-27722/com.example.neil.hvacbuilder W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: round.txt

Comment: And here is what is caught in the catch area.  I/System.out: In the catch  --  round.txt

Comment: there is no round.txt. Check for misspells

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of the assets folder ?

Comment: Make sure you aren't getting `" round"` when you do `button.getText().toString()`

Comment: I checked. No extra spaces in the front or back. I tried picking the other files, but the only one that works is the Square.txt file. This one has me baffled. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this worked, but I deleted all the txt files in my assets folder and then re-created them. Now it works just fine. Windows, should've known.